# Identify the recent story with a cross-dressing undertaker/necromancer?

Tags: story-identification, books

There was a book within last 18 months or so with the following characteristics:

- The main character was an undertaker and possibly a necromancer, and also a crossdresser
- He had a serial killer as assistant
- Another staff member was a female mermaid
- There was a competing undertaker in the town
- There was lots of humor, and some mysterious deaths
- It probably wasn't released by famous authors/publishers
- I found it through an online review blog, probably "[fantasy book critic](http://fantasybookcritic.blogspot.co.uk/)" or "[graeme's fantasy review](http://www.graemesfantasybookreview.com/)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, after some googling, I finally remembered the name. It's [A Festival of Skeletons](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/145375735X), by RK Astruc and Kay T. Holt.

[image: cover of "A Festival of Skeletons", showing six people standing. The man in the middle is wearing a pink dress]

Synopsis

> When Kamphor's west end sees a series of prostitutes murdered, its
>   citizens are fearful that a serial killer known as the Knife has
>   returned. But the mortician Sink, owner of Kamphor's finest morgue,
>   doesn't believe that the Knife has resumed killing - and he'd prove
>   it, if his former student and current hateful rival Damien Torvault
>   wasn't getting in the way.
>
> Sink and his two apprentices, handsome-if-loony Joshua Finkle and
>   merkind Vona Urgarth, investigate the murders on their own. Sink's
>   ability to tell exactly when and how a person will die just by
>   touching them earns him no friends, but it does yield some interesting
>   clues - as does Sink's other gift. The one which incites him to wear
>   women's clothing.
>
> The investigation is further complicated when Joshua's time is taken
>   up running a 15-Step program, and Vona becomes intrigued by a
>   repugnant yet strangely irresistible cook. Even Sink's next-door
>   neighbor, Policewoman Arifia Fowles, seems hell-bent on not just
>   hindering Sink but arresting him, regardless of a crime.